# iframe with javascript contents. Double click issue

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, html5-video

I have an iframe with a html5 video player and it also has some javascript that makes a Click Pause/Play event and it works fine if I visit the page directly. But if I access it from an iframe I must first double click it to get the single click event working.

Can anybody help please.

This is the javascript being executed.

```
<script>
var overlay = document.getElementById('video-overlay');
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var videoPlaying = false;
overlay.onclick = function() {
    if (videoPlaying) {
        video.pause();
        videoPlaying = false;
    }
    else {
        video.play();
        videoPlaying = true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: demo?????????????????

Comment: can you paste a fiddle for it? - or a link?

Comment: where is the script? in iframe or in main window?

Comment: You won't need the script or a demo. It's simply just an iframe thing. There probably is a js way around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the `iframe` is drawn as a separate web page, and as such needs to gain focus before the button inside it can be clicked.